# Devstack installation，oslo_log ImportError: cannot import name versionutils？

Tags: installation, devstack

I'm tring to install Devstack(stable/kilo) on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I tried many time,got the flowing error:

```
2016-07-20 13:24:59.856 | + /usr/local/bin/keystone-manage db_sync
2016-07-20 13:25:00.933 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |   File "/usr/local/bin/keystone-manage", line 6, in <module>
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |     from keystone.cmd.manage import main
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/manage.py", line 32, in <module>
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |     from keystone.cmd import cli
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |   File "/opt/stack/keystone/keystone/cmd/cli.py", line 24, in <module>
2016-07-20 13:25:00.934 |     from oslo_log import versionutils
2016-07-20 13:25:00.935 | ImportError: cannot import name versionutils
2016-07-20 13:25:00.950 | + exit_trap
2016-07-20 13:25:00.952 | + local r=1
2016-07-20 13:25:00.952 | ++ jobs -p
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + jobs=
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + [[ -n '' ]]
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + kill_spinner
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + echo 'Error on exit'
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | Error on exit
2016-07-20 13:25:00.953 | + generate-subunit 1469020399 701 fail
2016-07-20 13:25:01.941 | + [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-07-20 13:25:01.941 | + /home/chao/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-07-20 13:25:02.103 | df: '/mnt/hgfs': Protocol error
2016-07-20 13:25:02.139 | + exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually seen couple of times and a bug is reported as well:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1468465

Meanwhile you could try following steps and see if it helps:

- Unstack, Clean and reinstall python-pip. Then stack.sh and if issue comes again do install the missing package manually of particular version even though this is not the recommended way.